# Prove that $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$, and $\sqrt{5}$ can not all be terms of a single arithmetic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have come across a problem in a book on elementary mathematics that I am unable so solve.
The problem statement is :

"Show that the numbers $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$, and $\sqrt{5}$ cannot be terms of a single
arithmetic progression"

When I look at the hint for the problem in the back of the book it provides a partial proof by contradiction. They say : assume we have an arithmetic progression such that $m,n,p \in \mathbb{N}$
with :
\begin{align}
a_{m} & = \sqrt{2} \\
a_{n} & = \sqrt{3} \\
a_{p} & = \sqrt{5}
\end{align}
Here we know $m$, $n$, and $p$ must be pairwise distinct. They then tell the reader to use the formula for the general term of an arithmetic progression to compute $\frac{n-m}{p-m}$.

The formula referenced here is :
\begin{equation}
a_{k} = a_{1} + (k-1)r \;\; \forall k \geq 1
\end{equation}
Where $(a_{i})_{i \geq 1}$ is the progression and $r$ is the common difference between adjacent terms.

I am able to compute $\frac{n-m}{p-m}$ using the formula, but I do not understand why computing this can allow proving what the problem requests of the reader. Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: And what result do you get for $\frac{n-m}{p-m}$?

Comment: Note that in your query, $k$ must be a positive integer, and throughout the sequence, $r$ is a **fixed** real #.  The place to start is by assuming that $a_1 = \sqrt{2}, a_2 = \sqrt{3},$ and $a_m = \sqrt{5}$, for some positive integer $m$.  This means that $r = \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}$, and you are wondering whether there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $kr = \sqrt{5}.$  In my opinion, you should tackle this **specific** scenario before trying to answer the question as a whole.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A sequence includes $a_p=\sqrt2$, $a_q=\sqrt3$, $a_r=\sqrt5$ for some $1\leq p&lt;q&lt;r$. Can these be terms of an arithmetic progression? harmonic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3690033/a-sequence-includes-a-p-sqrt2-a-q-sqrt3-a-r-sqrt5-for-some-1-leq-pq)

Answer (score 3):

Following your hint, set

$$\sqrt{2}=a_m=a+(m-1)r$$

$$\sqrt{3}=a_n=a+(n-1)r$$

$$\sqrt{5}=a_p=a+(p-1)r$$

Then solving for $m,n,$ and $p$, we get

$$m=\frac{\sqrt{2}+r-a}{r}$$

$$n=\frac{\sqrt{3}+r-a}{r}$$

$$p=\frac{\sqrt{5}+r-a}{r}$$

Using the hint provided gives

$$\frac{n-m}{p-m}=\frac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{2}}$$

Now, since $n,m,p\in\mathbb{N}$, we know

$$\frac{b}{c}=\frac{n-m}{p-m}=\frac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{2}}\in\mathbb{Q}$$

Manipulating this expression gives us

$$b(\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{2})=c(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})$$

$$b\sqrt{5}-c\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{2}(b-c)$$

$$5b^2-2bc\sqrt{15}+3c^2=2(b-c)^2$$

$$\frac{5b^2+3c^2-2(b-c)^2}{2bc}=\sqrt{15}$$

Since the left hand side is rational but the right hand side irrational, we have arrived at a contradiction. We conclude that $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$, and $\sqrt{5}$ cannot be terms of a single
arithmetic progression

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to ignore the hint since in any arithmetic progression with  difference $r$ we must have $\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2 = br$ and $\sqrt 5 - \sqrt 2 = cr$ with $b,c \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: @PaulFrost And how would you reach a contradiction from that unless you try to claim something along the lines of $\frac{br}{cr}\in \Bbb Q$? Using the hint is basically necessary.

Comment: @Arthur My comment was in fact misleading. My only point was that the part of the hint which reduces the question to showing that $\frac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{2}}$ cannot be rational is unnecessarily complicated.